# Simplifying a complex circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

In my physics class, we recently learned how to compute RIV-tables for resistors using a diagram of a complex circuit, and we covered the properties of series and parallel resistors. However, I'm having some trouble simplifying the following circuit diagram and separating it into a conjunction of series and parallel resistors:

[image]

Can someone show me how to rearrange this to make it manageable? I left out the voltage and resistances because I'm not having trouble with that part of the problem - just with the rearrangement. But if anyone is curious, each resistor is $1\Omega$ and the battery is $5$ volts.

Answer (score 1):

Because all the resistors are the same, you can argue that from symmetry considerations there is no voltage drop on the center resistor (the vertical one). Therefore you can just ignore it and solve the problem as if it isn't there.